# IIS still load old javascript file. How to update or tell iis to load/take new javascript files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, deployment

I have deployed a new update on the server (MVC 5 apps). While iis load all my changes in views, css, etc. It doesnt load changes in javascript files. It still load an old version of javascript file.

[physical file in folder is different than iis loaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEGyW.png)

I have tried the following but nothing changes:

- Restarting IIS.
- Reseting ISS by using iisreset command
- Deleting website and re publish

I tried to duplicate one of the js file and renamed it. It works, since iis treat it as a new file. But this is not a solution. Is there any other solution to this issue?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/71885/1235365) on superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a hosting which you can't access to modify IIS setting. You can put the file version after script tag like `<script src='js/script.js?ver=1.1'></script>` to force iis get the new file when page load. When you edit content, then change that ver.

I implemented a custom js/css bundle used on my project, content version based on webapp version. When run a new build, all js and css will refresh:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebUtilities
{
    public static class CustomWebUtility
    {
        public static IHtmlString ScriptsRender(string bundlePath)
        {
            var contentVersion = GetWebappVersion();
            return Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}?ver=" + contentVersion + "\"></script>", bundlePath);
        }
        public static IHtmlString StylesRender(string bundlePath)
        {
            var contentVersion = GetWebappVersion();
            return Styles.RenderFormat("<link href=\"{0}?ver=" + contentVersion + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\">", bundlePath);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get web app version
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Webapp version with format: {major}.{minor}.{revision}</returns>
        public static string GetWebappVersion()
        {
            var version = string.Empty;
            Version assemblyVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            version = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", assemblyVersion.Major, assemblyVersion.Minor, assemblyVersion.Revision);

            return version;
        }
    }
}
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
// js
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
    "~/Scripts/pages/base.js",
    "~/Scripts/pages/somescript.js"));
// css
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
   "~/Content/css/base.css",
   "~/Content/css/base-mobile.css"));
```

Use it like common ScriptBundle and StyleBundle:

```
<head>
    @CustomWebUtility.ScriptsRender("~/bundles/js")
    @CustomWebUtility.StylesRender("~/Content/css")
</head>
```

Result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/pages/base.js?ver=1.2.21503"></script>
<link href="/Content/css/base.css?ver=1.2.21503" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the dynamic and static content compression setting on my website compression setting solve the problem for me.

[IIS website Compression setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i0do.png)